# SQL - Concatenation that yield different number of decimals

Tags: sql, concatenation, decimal, upsert

I need to concatenate two columns for an UpsertVerify column (I'm working in SQL server). When the value in column [B] = 22.23, it needs to be concatenated to column A in a manner where the column decimals remain the same (for [A] = example then [A] concatenated with [B] would yield example22.23).

Where I need help is when the value in column [B] only has a single decimal or no decimals the concatenated value should only yield one decimal. So if the value in column [B] = 22.3 or 22, the concatenated value should yield example22.3 or example22.0 respectively.

For example:

```
A       | B     | Upsert
example | 22.32 | example22.32
example | 22.1  | example22.1
example | 22    | example22.0
```

So for two decimals it needs to provide both those decimal values in the concatenated value, and for one decimal values it needs to provide the one decimal and yield a value of .0 for values with no decimals.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: And is 22.345 ever present? What to do in that case/others?

Comment: Always tag what database you're using. SQL is a standard,  not an implementation

Answer (score 1):

If it's Microsoft SQL server (guessed from your use of [] to quote the column names) you can:

```
CONCAT(a, FORMAT(b, '0.0#'))
```

If you want the expression to result in null if A or B is null, use

```
a + FORMAT(b, '0.0#')
```